# How do I make content fit the grid cells/div perfectly?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid, devextreme

So I don't know why I'm having such trouble making sure the contents fit its div. Here's what I have so far

```
<div id="container" class="charts-wrapper chart-container">  
  <div class="main-chart-container ">
    <img src = "https://picsum.photos/id/288/300/200" class = 'img-responsive mainn-chart'/>
  </div> 
  <div class="minor-chart-container">
      <img src = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200" class = 'img-responsive mainn-chart'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just as a note, solutions like background-image will not apply as they're actually just placeholders for other component code I'm looking into.

```
.charts-wrapper{
    display: grid;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    grid-template-columns: 35fr 10fr;
    column-gap: var(--dds-spacing-m);
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch; 
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    opacity:80%;
}
.main-chart-container{
    border: 5px solid red;
    grid-column: 1;
    display:flex;
    align-items:flex-start;
    align-content:flex-start;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:green;
    opacity: 40%;
}

.main-chart-container .mainn-chart{
    align-self:stretch;
}

.minor-chart-container{
    border: 5px solid red;
    grid-column: 2;
    // position: absolute;
    display:flex;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    // background-color:blue;
    opacity: 40%;
}
```

There's a lot of bloat code in the css sorry, I know- it was a result of my experiments.

Here are some pictures to describe what I'm trying to accomplish.[Widget1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/388u3.png)
[Expanded Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGgby.png)
As you can see here, when the widget expands, the grid expands as expected, and the image does have resizing capabilities, but I would like to make sure the image expands to the size of the grid cells. How would I change my CSS to accomplish this? Background-image will not help me here as the image is actually just a placeholder for the actual content I want to show which, if it helps, are both dx-charts from devextreme. We do not believe it's a devextreme chart issue, as it expands fine when it's the only chart in the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #ffff00;
        } 
        .charts-wrapper{
            display: grid;
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            grid-template-columns: 35fr 10fr;
            column-gap: var(--dds-spacing-m);
            align-items: stretch;
            align-content: stretch; 
            height:500px;
            background-color:yellow;
            opacity:80%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .main-chart-container{
            border: 5px solid red;
            grid-column: 1;
            display:flex;
            align-items:flex-start;
            align-content:flex-start;
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            background-color:green;
            opacity: 40%;
        }
        .main-chart-container .mainn-chart{
            width: 100%;
            height: 490px;
        }
        .minor-chart-container{
            border: 5px solid red;
            grid-column: 2;
            position: absolute;
            display:flex;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: auto;
            width: 90%;
            background-color:blue;
            opacity: 40%;
        }
        .minor-chart-container img{
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="container" class="charts-wrapper chart-container">  
        <div class="main-chart-container">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/288/300/200" class='img-responsive mainn-chart'/>
        </div> 
        <div class="minor-chart-container">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200" class='img-responsive mainn-chart'/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `height` + `width` instead `align-self:stretched` and eventually [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to avoid strectching but clipping to keep the pixel ratio of image.

example :

```css
/* removed some style for readability */
.charts-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  grid-template-columns: 35fr 10fr;
  column-gap: var(--dds-spacing-m);
}
.main-chart-container {
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 40%;
}
/* for both image */
.chart-container .mainn-chart {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position:/* see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position */ ;
}
.minor-chart-container {
  border: 5px solid red;
  opacity: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="charts-wrapper chart-container" style="--dds-spacing-m :1em">
  <div class="main-chart-container ">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/288/300/200" class='img-responsive mainn-chart' />
  </div>
  <div class="minor-chart-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200" class='img-responsive mainn-chart' />
  </div>
</div>
```